# To Symbols but not in array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I generate an Array:

```
self.attributes.keys.map(&:to_sym) - [:created_at, :updated_at] + [:warte]
```

The problem is, this code throws an error when I try to pass it to:

```
json.(self, self.attributes.keys.map(&:to_sym) - [:created_at, :updated_at] + [:warte] ) 

TypeError ([:id, :name, :vorname, ....] is not a symbol):
```

Because I would need the symbols simply split by ',':

```
 json.(self, :id, :name ....
```

And not in an Array like I have it now:

```
 json.(self, [:id, :name ....
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If your code is self-explanatory then it's not necessary to put that in, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the splat (`*`) operator:

```
json.(self, *(self.attributes.keys.map(&:to_sym) - [:created_at, :updated_at] + [:warte]))
```

[According to ruby-doc.org](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Array+to+Arguments+Conversion), the splat operator may be used to convert arrays into argument lists:

> ## Array to Arguments Conversion
>
> Given the following method:
>
> ```
> def my_method(argument1, argument2, argument3)
> end
> ```
>
> You can turn an Array into an argument list with * (or splat)
>   operator:
>
> ```
> arguments = [1, 2, 3]
> my_method(*arguments)
> ```
>
> or:
>
> ```
> arguments = [2, 3]
> my_method(1, *arguments)
> ```
>
> Both are equivalent to:
>
> ```
> my_method(1, 2, 3)
> ```

[Source](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Array+to+Arguments+Conversion)

Comment: Explain *WHY* the splat is going to help. Simply showing code only fixes this particular problem. Explaining what `*` does teaches why it's useful and is applicable to future questions the OP might have about this.

Comment: @theTinMan On it. I'm still looking for the ruby-doc documentation on this. I could've sworn there was a page on this, but haven't found it yet.

Comment: Ruby-Doc is for API documentation, i.e. documenting classes, modules, methods and constants. It really doesn't work for documenting language features. They try to shoehorn it by simply adding files with documentation written in prose, but unfortunately those don't have the nice indices and search boxes that the API docs have. It would be nice to have an equally indexable and searchable language reference with keywords, scoping rules, magic globals, syntax, semantics, method lookup algorithm, etc.